# Counting outputted results and send to database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, append

I am wanting output of data from my database to display in a numbered list. Say I have four names in the database. John, suzy, Tom, Linda. I then do a shuffle mix of those names and display them. They appear on my page like this...

undefined John

undefined Suzy

undefined Tom

undefined Linda

I want them to appear as

1 John

2 Suzy

3 Tom

4 Linda

I then want those numbers to send to my database in the order they were in and affiliated with the name they were next to. Right now when they send to my database, each record shows 4, so it is only counting the outputted rows.

I modified my existing script to enable my page to count as a list. However, the count output is not displaying on the page. It shows as undefined, but it is sending as the number 4 to my database.

Why is this not working?

I modified this JS

```
 //'<div class="shuffle_results">' + data[i].firstname + ' ' + data[i].lastname + '</div>' +
```

To

```
  '<div class="shuffle_results">' + data[i].drafted_order + ' '+ data[i].firstname + ' ' + data[i].lastname + '</div>' + 
       '<input type="hidden" name="count[]" value="' + data[i].drafted_order + '">' +
```

Full Code

```
$count = 0;
foreach ($array as $result) :
$count++;
$shuffle_count = $count;
    $shuffle_firstname = htmlentities($result['firstname']);
    $shuffle_lastname = htmlentities($result['lastname']);
    $shuffle_id = htmlentities($result['id']);
    $shuffle_username = htmlentities($result['username']);
    $shuffle_email = htmlentities($result['email']);
?>
    <input type="hidden" name="count[]" value="<?php echo $shuffle_count; ?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="firstname[]" value="<?php echo $shuffle_firstname; ?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="lastname[]" value="<?php echo $shuffle_lastname; ?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="id[]" value="<?php echo $shuffle_id; ?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="username[]" value="<?php echo $shuffle_username; ?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="email[]" value="<?php echo $shuffle_email; ?>">

<?php 

    endforeach;
    // only show this button if we have done a shuffle
     if ( isset($_POST['shuffle'] ) ) :
        echo '<input type="submit" value="Finalize Draft Order" name="insert">';
    endif;

?>
    </form>
<?php        
if (isset($_POST['insert'])) {
    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "", "", "");
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
        exit();
    }
    $draft_stmt2 = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO drafted_players (user_id, drafted_order, firstname, lastname, username, email) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");

  if ( false===$draft_stmt1|| false===$draft_stmt2 ) {
         // Check Errors for prepare
        die('Add to user players prepare() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($con->error));
    }
     $draft_stmt2->bind_param('iissss', $shuffle_id, $shuffle_count, $shuffle_firstname, $shuffle_lastname, $shuffle_username, $shuffle_email);

    foreach ($_POST['id'] as $i => $shuffle_id) {
        $shuffle_firstname = $_POST['firstname'][$i];
        $shuffle_lastname = $_POST['lastname'][$i];
        $shuffle_username = $_POST['username'][$i];
        $shuffle_email = $_POST['email'][$i];

        $draft_stmt2->execute() or
            die('Add to user players execute() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($draft_stmt2->error));
    }
```

JS

```
 var interval = setInterval(function(){ 
        if( i <= data.length){ 
            console.log( data[i] ); 
            $('#results').append('<div class="result">' +
                        //'<div class="shuffle_results">' + data[i].firstname + ' ' + data[i].lastname + '</div>' + 
                        '<div class="shuffle_results">' + data[i].drafted_order + ' '+ data[i].firstname + ' ' + data[i].lastname + '</div>' + 
                        '<input type="hidden" name="count[]" value="' + data[i].drafted_order + '">' +
                        '<input type="hidden" name="firstname[]" value="' + data[i].firstname + '">' +
                        '<input type="hidden" name="lastname[]" value="' + data[i].lastname + '">' +
                        '<input type="hidden" name="id[]" value="' + data[i].id + '">' +
                        '<input type="hidden" name="username[]" value="' + data[i].username + '">' +
                        '<input type="hidden" name="email[]" value="' + data[i].email + '">' +
                    '</div>');
           var $this = $('.shuffle_results:last'); 
            $this.show().animate({ 
                'left': 0 + 'px', 
                'bottom': + '0px' 
                //$(document).height() - (lineheight * data.length)
            }, { 
                duration: time 
            });
        i++;
        } else { 
            clearInterval(interval); 
        } 
    }, 3000); 
};
$(function(){  
    $('form[name="form"]').on('submit', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
       $.post('shuffle_results.php', function(data){ 
        var o = $.parseJSON(data); 
        displayResults(o); 
        });
        });
    });

//End test shuffle
    $(document).ready(function () {
```

Comment: I couldn't really follow your description what your code tries to do... but the 4 for each inserted db row comes from the fact that you are using the variable $shuffle_count in the beginning to populate the inputs and you are using the latest value of that loop (i.e. 4) in all database inserts (whereas you probably want to write some other value that you get from the post?).

Comment: I just want the outputted number to be like an ordered list. So output 1, 2, 3, 4. Where could I put the variables then? Do you have any clue why Js is outputting the values as undefined?

Comment: what does your console.log( data[i] ); output? I'm guessing (because it is not visible in the pasted code) that your data is initialized based on the php generated hidden fields - and therefore it doesn't contain drafter_number field (that is the name used in the db)... 
If you want the shuffled output to have running numbers 1,2,3,4 you can just use the loop index (i + 1) for the count number (?)

Comment: I get an error for this line ` '<div class="shuffle_results">' + data[i].drafted_order + ' '+ data[i].firstname + ' ' + data[i].lastname + '</div>' +`Saying it cannot read property drafted_order.` I'm not sure how to find the value for console.log(data[i[). What do you think I should do?

Comment: You can find the console log prints in the browser development tools (you should be able to find plenty of info about that on google - basically F12 opens it in multiple browsers and then you can see the outputs in 'Console' tab. You can try to replacing data[i].drafted_order calls with just (i + 1) if you are just trying to get a running number in your display (if I understood your goal - which I still doubt that I did). Additionally you probably need to fix the db storing to store a good value instead of the $shuffle_count (as explained in my first comment)

Comment: I know how to pull the console up just wasn't seeing anything for what you were mentioning. So like this? ` '<div class="shuffle_results">' + data[i + 1].drafted_order + ' '+ data[i].firstname + ' ' + data[i].lastname + '</div>' + 
                         '<input type="hidden" name="count[]" value="' + data[i + 1].drafted_order + '">' +`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87280/discussion-between-ejuhjav-and-becky).

Comment: @ejuhjav Sorry. I missed this. Let me know when you can do the chat.